# Java FX animation

Tags: java, animation, events, javafx, graphics

I have a set of lines on the screen. When I press a button "Start", the animation should be run. The animation goes like this:
 
1) show line 1, wait 1000 ms
 
2) show line 2,wait 1000 ms 
 
3) hide line 1, line 2 and show line 3, wait 1000 ms
 
   and so on.
 
When I press "Stop" I have to stop this animation and show an initial state. So my question: Do I have to use some classes of javafx.animation package? As I understood there are some template animations of the nodes like moving, rotating and other. But I need a sequence of showing and hiding of different nodes.
 Or should I run this sequence in a new Thread, through the ExecutorService, for example, and shutdown it when I press "Stop"? What is the best approach to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`Timeline`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html), with [event handlers on the `KeyFrame`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html#KeyFrame-javafx.util.Duration-javafx.event.EventHandler-javafx.animation.KeyValue...-):

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> { /* show line 1 */}),
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> { /* show line 2 */}),
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), e -> { 
        // hide line 1
        // hide line 2
        // show line 3
    }),
    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(3), e -> {/* etc. */}));
timeline.play();
```